# Ubuntu can't recognse my wifi

Tags: wireless

I know this is a common question, I've search and tried many solutions already. The thing is When I tried ubuntu with live cd, I can use my wifi although I needed to go to Software source to enable a setting. But after I actually installed Ubuntu It doesn't work anymore. I can't even enable that setting. This goes without saying that I'm a noob. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs concerning wifi in recent kernel drivers . Please check if  you're affected, e.g.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1086985
In any case you should report a bug. Wifi should simply work. If your bug report will be valid you'll most probably get assistance directly on launch pad.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the propriety drivers if there are any available for your device? 
Try following steps given in step 7 [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-12-10) . If it doesn't work run

```
nm-tool
```

and post output.

Comment: I went to step 7 when testing live cd version and it worked. Problem now is afer i've installed in hard drive but that method doesn't work. Anyway here is the output.

Comment: NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:25:64:41:34:73

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

Comment: Install and Try using jockey .